# Combining Events into one Handler, efficient?

Tags: c#, performance, hashcode

There are two parts to this question.

1. Is it better to have one event-specific function per object or combine object events and if so,
2. Would using hash codes to define the sender object and compare to find out whats being updated be efficient?

Example if code below.

My event function:

```
private void GeneralEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e){
        var senderHash = sender.GetHashCode();

        if (senderHash == tbDatabase.GetHashCode())
            Settings.DB.Default.Database = tbDatabase.Text;
        else if (senderHash == tbSchema.GetHashCode())
            Settings.DB.Default.Schema = tbSchema.Text;
}
```

My object definitions:

```
    // tbDatabase
    / 
    this.tbDatabase.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
    this.tbDatabase.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(62, 3);
    this.tbDatabase.Name = "tbDatabase";
    this.tbDatabase.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(210, 20);
    this.tbDatabase.TabIndex = 0;
    this.tbDatabase.LostFocus += new System.EventHandler(this.GeneralEventHandler);
    // 
    // tbSchema
    // 
    this.tbSchema.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(55, 3);
    this.tbSchema.Name = "tbSchema";
    this.tbSchema.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(217, 20);
    this.tbSchema.TabIndex = 1;
    this.tbSchema.LostFocus += new System.EventHandler(this.GeneralEventHandler);
```

I'm mainly just using it to update user settings on the fly. I save the settings file on exit.

Comment: Purely from a readability/maintainability aspect, if they do different things, give them their own handlers.

Comment: Different objects can have same hash code. Don't you assume that the hash code can be used as a unique identifier in your code?

Comment: Also, why even bother with the hash portion? Just check if sender == yourObject.

Comment: Define "better". Is this more readable or maintainable than two simpler handlers? As for "efficiency", writing weird code to save a few cycles in an event handler like that is absurd. How often will it be called? Millions of times in an inner loop? While the user frantically thrashes at the keyboard to keep up? No, there's no performance issue here. Use `sender == whatever`. For all I know, it's actually faster than your hashcode version -- not that it matters in the slightest.

Comment: What about if i split based on the object type? (ie textbox, checkbox, etc) and group based on that? It would better the readibilty while keeping the amount of functions low (i have alot of check boxes and text boxes)

Comment: Doesn't comparing my object to the sender in c# not compare everything about that object? As in a complete comparison? Or does it..

Comment: @MatthewWherry What actual problem are a few extra event handler methods causing for you?

Comment: No, @MatthewWherry it does not. If compares the references.

Comment: @MatthewWherry Write appropriate, idiomatic code. Don't worry about optimizing anything until you have a clear problem that needs to be fixed.

Comment: This all smells of [premature optimisation](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil) to me. It's really not clear what your trying to improve here.

Comment: Rather than use LostFocus, why not just do all the updates in a single Save button click.  But doing this way, I'd just keep them separate.  Put them in a partial class if they really bug you.

Comment: I have about 40-50 fields and a newbie at development. Thank you all for the input, it is very helpful

Comment: That is not pretty code, hard to maintain.  Above all, it just isn't necessary.  Winforms already provides this feature out-of-the-box.  Select the textbox in the designer, use (ApplicationSettings) in the Properties window to bind it to a setting.  No code required at all, easy peasy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer to have each object have its own event handler. Each handler in turn calls a method that "does the deed" without knowing who called it. If several objects "do the same thing" have them call the same "do-it" method.

You never know what the future brings - objects with combined event handlers now could diverge in what they need to do in the future.

Comment: Good answer: Additionally, the test for hash code might be fast, but it's still a test that can consume time and energy.  Why not take the opportunity for good code organization - which is really what is important here - and then gain a teensy bit of optimization in the bargain.